# Too many re-renders using useState hook

Tags: reactjs

I am building multi language project with 1i8n.Next.When i am mapping trough defined languages and trying to store in a state React throws an error **Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop**

Here is the code.

```
const supportedLanguages = ["en", "fr"];

function LanguageSwitcherComp(props) {
  const { children, i18n, t, history, match } = props;
  const [lang, setLang] = useState();
  const changeLanguage = nextLang => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(nextLang, () => {
      const newUrl = `/${nextLang}/${t(match.params.page)}`;
      console.log(newUrl);
      history.push(newUrl);
    });
  };
  const handleClickSelectLanguage = (event, index) => {
    changeLanguage(supportedLanguages[index]);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {supportedLanguages.map((option, index) => (
        setLang(index)

      ))}
      <button onClick={event => handleClickSelectLanguage(event, lang)}>English</button>
      <button onClick={event => handleClickSelectLanguage(event, lang)}>French</button>

      <Link to={`/${i18n.language}/${t("hello")}`}>{t("hello")}</Link>
      <Link to={`/${i18n.language}/${t("about")}`}>{t("about")}</Link>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const LanguageSwitcher = withRouter(
  withTranslation("routes")(LanguageSwitcherComp)
);
```

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
  {supportedLanguages.map((option, index) => (
    setLang(index)
  ))}
```

This code inside the return is causing the issue,
you are trying to set the language again and again.
once you call the setLang and it will re-render your component again it will call the same setLang, so it becomes in a loop.
is you are trying to set a default language add it in useState argument

`const [lang, setLang] = useState(supportedLanguages[0]);`

```
const supportedLanguages = ["en", "fr"];

function LanguageSwitcherComp(props) {
  const { children, i18n, t, history, match } = props;
  const [lang, setLang] = useState(supportedLanguages[0]);
  const changeLanguage = nextLang => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(nextLang, () => {
      const newUrl = `/${nextLang}/${t(match.params.page)}`;
      console.log(newUrl);
      history.push(newUrl);
    });
  };
  const handleClickSelectLanguage = (event, index) => {
    changeLanguage(supportedLanguages[index]);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={event => handleClickSelectLanguage(event, lang)}>English</button>
      <button onClick={event => handleClickSelectLanguage(event, lang)}>French</button>

      <Link to={`/${i18n.language}/${t("hello")}`}>{t("hello")}</Link>
      <Link to={`/${i18n.language}/${t("about")}`}>{t("about")}</Link>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const LanguageSwitcher = withRouter(
  withTranslation("routes")(LanguageSwitcherComp)
);
```

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: Let me know the actual requirement. removing the map from that return will fix the too many renders issue for sure

Comment: yes it starts working when i am removing setLang(index).But i need to store the index in the state

Comment: You are trying to store the index in a loop and after every render it will call same and it gets into a infinite loop again and again, also when you are trying to `setLang(index)` in a map function it will initially set 0 and on the map rotation immediately it will set to 1 , because it is inside the map loop, 
you can use `useEffect` hook to set the index only for the first time, but not using the map, just thing the loop running and the logic